# Stripe - Get average payments pr customer

Tags: php, api, stripe-payments

Im working with a module get alot of statistics but i got stuck with a problem. I want to make a statistic about how many stripe payments a customer do in average (subscriptions). Like i want to know how along a user is subscripted in average.

What i tried to do so far is to get ALL payments (heavy data) and count each customer id, but this is really heavy and the website was working on the process like 20 minutes (167000 payments). Any of you ever wanted this functionality and found a solution for the issue? Or anyone got an idea how i can solve this problem?

Hope you can help me get started in the right direction so i can find a solution for this. :)

- Thanks for the time.

Comment: I don't think you can do something about it, if there is no api for the feature you need, you have to bear it :(

Comment: Thats really sad. Could be interesting statistics to see how many payments we get pr subscription in average :/

Comment: Generally most APIs are slow and man your fetching 167000 records

Comment: I do think your also maintaining some kind of payment details in your database, I think if you use that instead of API, that improve things little bit

Comment: We are using magento and nothing about subscription is stored in database only a specified group which is changed by events from stripe.

Comment: You can record in your database the payment gateway your customer uses during their purchase (if you provide multiple payment gateway), from there you can then keep a record of the customers using this specific payment gateway.

Comment: @hungrykoala we use stripe only, but no information from stripe is saved each time they pay for the subscription. :/

Comment: Are you using other payment gateways? Maybe you can create a trigger if they choose stripe run this code. A simple onclick function would suffice for this.

Comment: Nope. Only using stripe. But a onclick wont get everytime they pay for their subscription stripe @hungrykoala

Comment: Are you hosting your Stripe form? If you do then you can get that information during their payment.

Comment: Dont think you understand @hungrykoala. Dont care of the payment on the store. Im interested in how many times Stripe charges subscriptions foreach customers before cancellation. That have nothing to do with the homepage at all. Therefore i need to use their API :)

Comment: Oh! you can do that with the API why not fetch those information everyday and store it inside your DB so that you don't do bulk updates

Comment: Yea right now also considering to check for new subscription payments each day and add them to DB. But then i guess i have to make something so i get alle the old data, because its important data :)